# Why doesn't Mockito RETURNS_DEFAULT return a default String?

Tags: java, mockito

In the following example (mockito 1.10.19):

```
    MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass .class, RETURNS_DEFAULTS);
    String s = myClass.getName();
```

Why does this result in `s == null` rather than an empty String?

It indeed promised `null` for a String in [ReturnsEmptyValues](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsEmptyValues.html). But it seems so obvious to return `""` that I'm wondering if there is a reason for it not to.

EDIT: updated version to 1.10.19 from 1.8, because no documentation is available anymore for 1.8.

Comment: Link is broken...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It wasn't thought of at design time and now for stability reason, this behavior didn't change.

There's an non exposed answer called [ReturnsMoreEmptyValues](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsMoreEmptyValues.html) that returns as the type name suggests more empty values.

You could also take a look at the [Mockito.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS) answer that use ReturnsMoreEmptyValues internally and features more interesting debug informations.

*Note this links to 1.10.19 version javadoc, however this behavior remains unchanged in version 2.x at the time of this writing.*

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score 11):

From the link you posted;

> Default answer of every Mockito mock.
>
> - Returns appropriate primitive for primitive-returning methods
> - Returns consistent values for primitive wrapper classes (e.g. int-returning method retuns 0 and Integer-returning method returns 0,
>     too)
> - Returns empty collection for collection-returning methods (works for most commonly used collection types)
> - Returns description of mock for toString() method
> - **Returns null for everything else**

From the FAQ:

What values do mocks return by default?

> **In order to be transparent and unobtrusive** all Mockito mocks by
>   default return 'nice' values. For example: zeros, falseys, empty
>   collections or nulls.

It was probably done to stay consistent with any other methods which return null for any other non-collection, non-primitive Wrapper objects.

You can always implement your own [Answer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) to pass to `mock` which returns empty strings for String returning methods.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because the designer of Mockito decide to use that as a default
2. Because null is also the default value of fields in a Java object

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mockito code for all non collections and non simple types it returns null. String is an subtype of Object and it's "empty" value is null, not "".IMHO It is a design decision if you represent empty value for string as null or "".

Answer (score 0):

```
YourService service = mock(YourService.class, RETURNS_MOCKS);
when(service.callYourFunc()).thenReturn(mockValue);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serrviceParent, "service", service);
```

**serrviceParent** is service that you are testing and it contains field **YourService** that couldn't return **mockValue** that you want