# Mocking a method that returns optional is returning Optional.empty(), even when that method never returns that value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In the following unit test the values of `test1` (`Optional[1]`) and `test2` (`Optional[2]`) make sense, but `test3` equals `Optional.empty`. How is it possible that I am getting back empty when no code path in my mocks or in `A::call` returns this value?

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

class MockitoTest {

    public static class A {
        public Optional<Long> call(final long i) {
            try {
                return Optional.of(i*2);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                var a = 1;
            }
            return Optional.of(-1L);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        final var a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
        Mockito.when(a.call(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(1L));
        Mockito.when(a.call(2)).thenReturn(Optional.of(2L));

        var test1 = a.call(1); // Optional[1]
        var test2 = a.call(2); // Optional[2]
        var test3 = a.call(3); // Optional.empty

        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a Mockito feature. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/191

Comment: @tgdavies Woah. How is that a desirable result? I was expecting `null` or an `Exception` to be thrown.

Comment: Because a method whose return type is `Optional` should never return null. For such methods, an empty optional is the "no value" result, not null.

Comment: But it's a Mock and not a real-world test. I guess my understanding of how Mockito works isn't the same as what the developers intend.

Comment: It's a mock, so you can tell it to return whatever you like. But by default, if you don't tell it, it returns a default value.

Comment: Isn't the default value always going to be `null` in all other cases?

Comment: They tried to use "nice" default return values. For most object return types that is going to be `null`. But if the return type is a collection, for example, the default return value will be an empty collection.

Comment: @Slaw I guess from that perspective it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`A#call` is never executed by your test, since `a` is a Mockito mock. Your real code is never executed, so it doesn't matter what it is.

Mockito mocks only do what you tell them to do with `when` and `thenReturn`/`thenAnswer`/`thenThrow`/etc.

If you do not stub a method, Mockito will return a "default value" specific to the type. That means:

- 0 for numeric types (int, long, float, double) and their boxed equivalents (Integer, Long, Float, Double)
- Empty collections and maps for collection types (List, Set, Map)
- Empty optionals for optionals
- …
- `null` for Strings and any other type

References:

- [How about some stubbing?](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2)
- [Changing default return values of un-stubbed invocations (Since 1.7) Link icon](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#defaultreturn)
- [Why doesn't Mockito RETURNS_DEFAULT return a default String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604402/why-doesnt-mockito-returns-default-return-a-default-string)

Comment: I guess my surprise comes from the Collections and Optionals part. I was expecting `null` in both those cases since they aren't types built into the language, they're libraries. It feels inconsistent in the same way that String returns null like any other type. Why not "empty String"?

Comment: @Ian "It wasn't thought of at design time and now for stability reason, this behavior didn't change." (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8604943/112968). Only the Mockito devs can answer the "why"

Comment: @Ian I believe the idea is to make mocks easier to create. Collections and optionals might as well be part of the language given how fundamental they are, even if they are just from the standard library. It is widely accepted that methods which return a collection or an optional should never return null (or at least never be designed so that null is a valid result). Such methods should return an "empty" object instead. So, Mockito follows that convention _by default_, meaning you don't have to stub it yourself.